# Prevent to start "Debugger-Windows" from first application start in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I start a program from Visual Studio it also starts several (about 6) additional windows I guess they show some resource information.

My problem is that those windows seems to freeze the whole progam. I cannot close them and have to restart Visual Studio. Is there a way to prevent them to open when I start a application from Visual Studio?

**EDIT**(Screenshot added):

[image]

**EDIT:** After a downvote without a comment, it looks like i have to add my affords:

- Googled over an hour, but because those boxes crashes I dont see what they are supose to be. So I dont know for sure what to look for.
- Enabled and dissabled all Debbuging option without any effect.

**EDIT:** Its a default C# WPF app.

**EDIT:** Title

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: So that's what you see when launching a new WPF app that you haven't modified? I'd try reinstalling Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes I have reinstalled it. It still opens those windows. What I have done on the screenshot is to move them. They are grouped at one position normally. I Also have found out that those Debug-Windows from http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/esta7c62.aspx If you close them once they wont show up next time. But I could not find out how to prevent to open them for the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a TeamViewer issue.
Debug doesnt work in with TeamViewer running.

- You have to close TeamViewer.
- Start debugger
- Close all debugging windows (Watch, Memory)
- End debugger
- You can now open Teamvierwer again

Source:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817590/microsoft-visual-studio-express-2013-for-windows-desktop-hangs-on-debug